# PyMongo, Graphing

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have several mongo databases (some populated with collections and documents, some empty) and I am trying to parse through them and create a graph for the contents.  I am planning on making nodes for each db, each collection, and each key in the collection, and the from each key to the value (so skipping the pages).  Here is my code for getting the graph.

```
for db in dbs:
  G.add_node(db)
  for col in c[db].collection_names():
    G.add_node(col)
    G.add_edge(db, col, weight = 0.9)
    for page in c[db][col].find():
      if (u'_id' in page.viewvalues()):
        pprint.pprint(page)
        G.add_node(page[u'_id'])
        G.add_edge(col, page[u'_id'], weight = 0.4)
        for key, value in page.items():
          G.add_node(key)
          G.add_edge(col,  key, weight = 0.1)
          G.add_node(value)
          G.add_edge(key,value)
```

My Problem is that I never pass the if statement `if (u'_id' in page.viewvalues()):`  I know I am getting pages (if I print the pages before the if statement I get a few thousand printed but the if statement is always false.  What have I done wrong in accessing the dictionary returned from the `find()` query?  Thanks.

EDIT:

I should probably also mention that when I do something like this

```
for i in page:
```

instead of the of the if statement it works for a bit and then breaks saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` and I figured this was when it hit an empty page or when `find()` returned no pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import pymongo

c = pymongo.Connection()
dbs = c.database_names()

for db in dbs:
    for col in c[db].collection_names():
        for page in c[db][col].find():
            if '_id' in page:
                for key, value in page.iteritems():
                    print key, value
```

You always get a dictionary while iterating over pymongo cursor (which is returned by `find()`). So, you can just check if there is an `_id` key in the dictionary.

By the way, you can specify what fields to see in the results by providing the `fields` argument to the `find()`.

Comment: Does that work when you have a collection that has no data in it?

Comment: Then, find will just return nothing.

Comment: how do you check for that? (It is throwing that error saying not a dict type that I mentioned in the edit)

Comment: If there is no records in the collection, `c[db][col].find()` will just return empty and the loop won't even start. If there is any data in the collection, when looping over the pymongo cursor will return a page dict.

Comment: I've checked locally - it works for all my databases and collections - even empty ones. Are you getting any errors while trying the code I've provided?

Comment: Nope, your code is perfect,  The error comes when I try and save the node.

    G.add_node(value)

I think it is because some of the values are dictionaries themselves, that would make sense

Comment: May be, you can limit the number of fields you see in `page` by specifying `fields` argument to `find()`, like `c[db][col].find(fields=['_id', 'something else'])`, or `c[db][col].find(fields={'_id': False})`.

Comment: I think I just need to check for however deep the objects are going.  I will play around a little more with it and see how it goes.  I really do appreciate your help on this.  Thanks again, and for earlier today too.